# Please help me identify the grammatical part of "done"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Construction was recently finished on a two-year renovation, undertaken because the original glass had begun to crack.

what does "undertaken" function here? Is it a participle, but I do not see how it is related to the main sentence? Part of the "was done"( was finished, was undertaken)? But the order seems to be wrong and should be "was undertaken" first then "was finished"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Construction was recently finished on a two-year renovation [that was] undertaken because the original glass had begun to crack.

The participle phrase "undertaken..." modifies "renovation". You could see it as a relative clause, as above, that has been reduced to a participle phrase.
It is an adjunct because the first part of the sentence is grammatical without it. It just explains why the renovation was done.